# PHPCI Deployment

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I want to use PHPCI to build and deploy my Symfony project.
So far I've been successful in the build part.

My problem now is copying and deploying the files so that it can be seen by the webserver.

I've used the copy_build plugin, but it copies the whole build folder and not just the contents.

So my deployment folder becomes like this

```
/var/www/project-root/[build-number]/[codes]
```

instead of just

```
/var/www/project-root/[codes]
```

My phpci.yml looks like this

```
success:
copy_build:
    directory: '/var/www/project-root'
    wipe: true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the shell plugin to copy the build to the deployment folder.

The documentation can found at https://www.phptesting.org/wiki/Shell-Plugin